# Return the First and Last Elements in a List Python, why does this method not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm supposed to create a function that takes a list of elements and return the first and last elements as a new list.

```
def first_last(lst)
    return lst[0, -1] 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Why does this not work? I looked at the answer. It's

```
def first_last(lst):
    return [lst[0], lst[-1]]
```

I don't get it, can someone explain?

Comment: Don't get what? It doesn't work because, as the error message tells you, list indices have to be integers like `0` and `-1`, not a tuple like `0, -1`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list access tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  It doesn't work because that's not how the Python language is defined.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, there exists no such list indexing syntax. Just because it makes sense to you does not mean it's valid Python code. Since no such syntax exists for standard Python lists, to Python, it looks like you are trying to use the tuple literal `0, -1` (which is equivalent to `(0, -1)`) as a single index to your list. Python lists do not support indexing via tuples, therefore the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things with that bracket notation. You can retrieve *one element*:

```
return lst[0]  # the 0th element of the list
```

or you can retrieve *a continuous slice of elements*:

```
return lst[1:9:2]  # a sublist containing every 2nd element from index 1 until 9
                   #   so, incides 1, 3, 5, and 7.
```

The "solution" here is extracting the 0th element and the last element of the original list, and putting them in a new list. Technically, you *could* use a list slice to do this, by giving it a "step size" equal to the length of the list minus one:

```
return lst[::len(lst) - 1]
```

but that's less clear to look at than the solution you've been given.

---

Importantly, there are some classes in third-party libraries (e.g. `numpy.array`) that *do* let you use `array[2, 3]` syntax. This is not a base language feature, and it's accomplished by overriding the method that gets called when you use bracket notation to access something on the object, to make it not return an error when you put in the tuple `(2, 3)`. In the case of `np.array`, it's to make it more familiar to mathematicians - `array[2, 3]` functions similarly to `array[2][3]`.